# change bg color of button on press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i know this question may sound stupid to you guys, but i am a beginner so need some expert help and i want to ask that is there anyway to change background-color of the button when pressed, i mean when clicked it changes to different background-color and when released sets to default (when pressed via mouse). i am trying but when i set function to trigger on "keypress" the function doesn't trigger but when i use "click" it works but doesn't change to default when released...please help me..

javascript/jquery:

```
function initAll(){
$("#submitBtn").on('keypress', sendMessage);
}

function sendMessage(){
    $("#submitBtn").css('background-color', 'Red');
}
```

html:

```
<input type="button" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtnnm" value="Send" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont need JS - just the `:active` state

```css
#submitBtn:active {
    background: red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7VURa/1/)

Comment: man ur awesome!! you solved it under just 5min...thank you veryy much... =D

Comment: :) a guy named Kim left a comment saying that `:active` is a CSS3 feature only - that was a reply

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way (easier to read in my opinion):

```
function initAll() {
   $("#submitBtn").click(sendMessage);
}

function sendMessage () {
   $("#submitBtn").css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

---

Make sure you call the code `initAll()` on `$(document).ready()`. Otherwise, the code might run when there are no matching elements on the page.

Comment if you need more advice!

Comment: @Hiddle i've already mentioned it that i've tried click but it doesn't change to default color when released...btw "Zoltan" answered the question and really thx for giving your time to sort out the problem... =)

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery mousedown and mouseup functions: http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/ and http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css("background", "red");        
  });
  $("button").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).css("background", "green");        
  });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CdzSB/

Comment: Thank you very much...=) its working but for this i'll have to extend the code, i'll have to set up two different function, btw zoltan solved the problem. we can just add #submitBtn:active on the css side and its working perfectly..anyways thanks for giving your precious time.. =D

Answer (score 0):

you should use css class like this and use jquery to add class to body tag when button click

```
.changeback{
background-color: #333333;
background-image: url('images/background9.jpg');
 }
```

and jquery code should be like this

```
$("#send").click(function(){
  $('body').addClass('changeback');
}):
```

Comment: but it will not set the color to default when released, btw i've got the answer and thank you very much for helping me =)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#submitBtn').mousedown(function() {
        $('#submitBtn').css('background-color', 'Red');
    }).mouseup(function() {
        $('#submitBtn').css('background-color', 'Blue');
    });
});
```

Basically, when the user presses the button it turns red, and when the user stops pressing it it turns blue.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you very much...=) its working but for this i'll have to extend the code, i'll have to set up two different function, btw zoltan solved the problem. we can just add #submitBtn:active on the css side and its working perfectly..anyways thanks for giving your precious time.. =D

Comment: @AndroidGuy No problem! Glad I was able to help, even if a bit. :) You can atleast re-use this when you want to do certain functions on these conditions. :) Could it be possible you up-vote my post? Remember that's the best way to say thanks. ;)

Comment: Lavaque sorry but i can't, because to vote-up one needs to be above 15 Reputation....So, God bless you =)

Comment: Oh yeah that's right, I forgot about that. LOL. You're welcome anyway. :)